# What is the justification to teach the (redundant) use of parentheses in multiplications?

Tags: primary-education

Example: 5 x 18 = (5 x 10) + (5 x 8) instead of 5 x 10 + 5 x 8?

Comment: The teacher must have been offended by dear Aunt Sally and refused to excuse her.

Comment: If I see `5 x 10 + 5 x 8` then very first thing I need to do is think about order of precedence and mentally map that to `(5 x 10) + (5 x 8)` anyway. So certainly presenting it as such up front saves me a step. What would be the justification for not doing it? You think that the extra step is worthwhile in itself? Or just that you personally find doing it so intuitive you think everyone else will too?

Comment: It's actually required if you're brave enough to use Windows Calculator in standard mode. :-/

Comment: @RobertColumbia or somebody forgot to [email the teacher's dad a shark](https://xkcd.com/992/).

Comment: The parentheses in (5 x 10) + (5 x 8) are only redundant *because* we have a convention that says 5 x 10 + 5 x 8 should be parsed as (5 x 10) + (5 x 8) rather than as 5 x ((10 + 5) x 8) or any of the other possible ways. You need to teach that convention before you can rely on that convention. Using parentheses is pretty convenient to teach that convention.

Comment: This was to later bother developers with warnings like https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/1.26.0/RuboCop/Cop/Lint/AmbiguousOperatorPrecedence

Answer (score 27):

Early in their education (even well into learning algebra), students don't naturally see the structure within algebraic expressions. It takes a bit of mental overhead to see that 5 x 10 + 5 x 8 is the sum of two products.

Presenting the expression as (5 x 10) + (5 x 8) saves students the mental overhead, letting them focus on the message that's trying to be communicated.

I recently found myself adding unnecessary parentheses to first-order logical formulas in order to make them easier to read, and thus more effective at quickly communicating the idea I was trying to get across.

Comment: That's a great analogy! Anyone who's been through a college-level math course immediately recognizes PEMDAS, so much so that we don't even remember the days when it wasn't as intuitive. But logical connectives trip lots of people up, even experienced mathematicians. Despite it being [fairly standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#Order_of_precedence), lots of people don't know this precedence ordering.

Comment: Reducing that mental overhead is also really helpful in any kind of computer programming involving math; saves you time while giving you more confidence that the code is doing what you think it's doing

Comment: @Silvio Mayolo: I also like the logical connectives comparison. In the little bit of logic I've worked with, I've found the conventions for understood parentheses like learning a 2nd language, a language totally unnecessary for most anyone NOT specializing in mathematical logic. Indeed, this isn't even what the vast majority of people in mathematical logic need to know all that well anyway. Despite this unimportance (except in certain formal meta-logic proofs), many textbooks seem to expect people to learn this language very well, **(continued)**

Comment: or have machine-like reading ability for complicated logical expressions. In my own writing I've mostly ignored each approach, and freely use different bracketing symbols for better comprehension and short-cut terms (e.g. "(line 3)" rather than writing out what "line 3" is). For example, see the style used in [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/94483/13130). I think it would be better to spend less time testing the evaluation of "artificial interpretation problems" like $5 \times 10 + 5 \times 8$ **(continued)**

Comment: and to spend more time on simply explaining WHY the expression is ambiguous without some conventions (order of operations and what it means to have expressions in parentheses). Of course, when one gets to algebra, one needs to know how to evaluate something like $ab + cd.$ But I think it's wasteful to deal with these expressions BEFORE the study of algebra.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I am intrigued at what country you’re from where they’d only teach PEMDAS (or, as I learned it in the UK, BODMAS (but my kids have learned as BIDMAS)) in a “college-level math course”. I’d learned this (and so did my kids) by at least age 12.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro: I have often seen things written in [prenex normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form) without any parentheses for the quantifiers (because it is implied that they range over the entire expression). I have also seen people claim that quantifiers "normally" bind more tightly than some, most, or all other logical operators.  I find the former style easier to read, personally.

Comment: @Darren In the US here. We learned it in like 3rd or 4th grade (age 8-10 or so). But I've met lots of, to put it charitably, mathematically challenged adults who have since forgotten all of that. My point was more "anyone who has bothered to get a college degree is intelligent enough to be able to parse this".

Comment: @anjama Especially when dealing with operators which aren’t handled uniformly across languages. For example exponentiation is left-associative in some languages (Python for example) and right-associative in others (Wolfram Alpha for example), so `4^3^2` is ambiguous without parenthesis, and possibly misunderstood without a proper knowledge of the language in the absence of parenthesis.